# How to write a test for parseFile in Go

Tags: go

I have a parseFile function that given a file parsing for certain information and returns a struct. How do I write a test for this function?
With Java, I could have a file in the test folder but I not sure how to best do it in Go.

Thanks and regards

Comment: You could have a file locally like that or it could just be a string literal in code (depends on how the method is written, if it takes filepath then ofc you need to read a file, if it takes file contents as string or bytes then you don't). Typical work flow would be something like this; 1) declare the expected result 2) call parseFile method 3) compare expected to actual

Answer (score 3):

You can do exactly the same in Go, albeit it is handled a bit differently.
Create a folder called "testdata" next to your `*_test.go` files.

This folder [is by convention ignored by the go tools](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/golang-nuts/VPVlIiO5yXw), as are all folders beginning with an underscore. This is why I name my resources directories for web applications `_components` instead of `bower_components`, for example.

Now, you can access said folder with a relative path from your tests, and it won't pollute your namespace or sth.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to commit a file to the same folder as your test, and read in a relative path by way of `os.Open("./path_to_file")`.

If the issue is that you're looking for a file in a specific location, I'd recommend parameterizing whichever method loads the information to accept different filepaths.